# Installing mysql in Rasbian installs mariadb

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, mysql

I'm trying to install mysql server on my Raspberry pi 3 Model B. I've updated the packages and I've upgraded the packages using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

When I install mysql server using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The end result is that mariadb is installed. Why does this happen?

Comment: Maria DB is a drop in replacement for MySQL

Comment: [Debian 9 Stretch released](https://www.debian.org/News/2017/20170617) ... *In Stretch, the default MySQL variant is now MariaDB. The replacement of packages for MySQL 5.5 or 5.6 by the MariaDB 10.1 variant will happen automatically upon upgrade.*